# Conditional in Javascript that pushes "not found" statement when no criteria matches

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out a way for my code to loop through all instances of an object.

So far I made a function that when an checkbox is "checked" it lists off within an array the values of each "checked" input. It then loops through an object and pushes the values of each variable in my object that matches the total values that I've selected.

So all's well and good so far, the issue is, I want a "not found" statement to show up when the values selected don't match anything in the object. But it's listing off too early when it's false instead of only when nothing at all matches.

Also I'm pretty new to JS so if there was a way simpler way to do this in pure JS i'm all ears.

HTML

```
<body onload="resultsList()">
  
   <div class="filter">
   <form name="testform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="fruit">Fruit<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="vegetable">Vegetable<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="red">Red<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="yellow">Yellow<br>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
  
<div id="filteredResults"></div>
```

JS

```
    // Object containing all food

const food = {
  count: 3,
  results: [
        {
            name: "Apple",
      keyword: ["fruit", "red"],
      description: "An apple is a red fruit.",
        },
    {
            name: "Banana",
      keyword: ["fruit", "yellow"],
      description: "A banana is a yellow fruit.",
        },
    {
            name: "Bell Pepper",
      keyword: ["vegetable", "yellow", "red"],
      description: "A bell pepper is a sometimes red or yellow vegetable.",
        },
  ]
};

let results = food.results;

function resultsList() { // Lists all stratagems on load
    let tab = ``;
  
    for (let r of results) {
    tab += 
   `<p>${r.name}</p>
    <p>${r.description}</p><br>`
    ;
  }
    document.getElementById("filteredResults").innerHTML = tab;
};

const filter_children = (document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=filter]'));
let enabled_filters = [];
// Filter function
filter_children.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    
    enabled_filters = 
      Array.from(filter_children)
      .filter(i => i.checked) // Filters out checked inputs
      .map(i => i.value) // Maps filtered values into array
    
    // Converts array into string
    let text = enabled_filters.toString();
    let tab = ``;
    // Loops through all results
    for (let r of results) {
      // Pulls keyword array from object
      k = r.keyword;
      // Checks for objects that have every correlated value selected as a keyword
      let true_results = enabled_filters.every(i => k.includes(i));
      
      if (true_results == true) { // If true, do this
        tab += 
        `<p>${r.name}</p>
        <p>${r.description}</p><br>`
        ;
      } else {
        tab = 
        `<p>Nothing fits the criteria.</p><br>`
        ;
      };
       
    };
    
    document.getElementById("filteredResults").innerHTML = tab;
    
  });
});
```

Comment: The code needs to if any results have been found and add that HTML *after* the loop determines nothing has been found. Here, if `tab === ''`, nothing has been found, so you *could* use that as your condition.

Comment: Oh man duh, it was so obvious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's always obvious once you see it ;) Glad you worked it out.